# exchange number system by using C language?

Tags: c

I am learning about C language, but I have a question. I want to make such that program,

```
input number :
```

after input number, for example if I put 32165 then computer shows

```
The decimal 32165 is the octal number 076645, and the hexadecimal number is 0x7da5.
The octal number 32165 is the decimal 13429, and the hexadecimal number is 0x3475.
The hexadecimal number 32165 is the decimal 205157, and the octal number is 0620545.
```

I can do first line such

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("input number: ");
    int num;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("The decimal %d is the octal number %o, and the hexadecimal number is %x.", num, num, num);
}
```

but I don't know how to do second, third line.

how can exchange other number system only use one scanf()?

Thanks for your reading.

Comment: Have you tried `scanf` with `%o` or `%x`?

Comment: By the way, in the `printf` call you posted, I assume you meant `%x`, not `%h`.

Comment: You could also use `strtol` and, if your system has it, one of the nonstandard `itoa` functions.

Comment: But no, you can't take the input digits `32165` and simultaneously interpret them as decimal, octal, and hexadecimal with a single `scanf` call.  But you could read them as a string, and then convert that string using three separate `sscanf` (not `scanf`) calls.

Comment: Read the number in as a string, then use `sscanf` to perform the conversions you want.

Comment: Oh, I never heard itoa(),strtol function before. thanks for notice me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put one of the suggestions from the comments to work:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

enum { MAX_NUM_LENGTH = 100 };

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[MAX_NUM_LENGTH + 1];

    int number;
    printf("Input number: ");
    if (!scanf("%d", &number)) {
        fputs("Input error!\n\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("The decimal number %d is the octal number 0%o, "
           "and the hexadecimal number is 0x%x.\n", number, number, number);

    int temp;
    sprintf(buffer, "%d", number);
    sscanf(buffer, "%o", &temp);

    printf("The octal number 0%o is the decimal number %d, "
           "and the hexadecimal number is 0x%x.\n", temp, temp, temp);

    sprintf(buffer, "%d", number);
    sscanf(buffer, "%x", &temp);

    printf("The hexadecimal number 0x%x is the decimal number %d, "
           "and the octal number is 0%o.\n", temp, temp, temp);
}
```

Comment: sprintf(buffer, "%d", number);// Is sprintf() for print to screen? what did this line do? could you explain me?? thanks for your help:)

Comment: `sprintf()` "prints" into a string. Please refer to the manual: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/